# Nested Rails Objects Forms and haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a rails model class that belongs to other models in the application.. now i want to render an edit form in order to update the records of the relevant objects respectively.. this i have found very confusing..

below is a sample class to illlustrate what i want to achieve:

```
     class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base` 
          belongs_to :user
          belongs_to :department
          belongs_to :invoice, :class_name => "Department"

     end
  `
```

this is also followed by the attempt i made at rendering the edit form. I am not familiar with the haml syntax and it appears to have very little documentation that cover this case.

```
= form_for :booking, :url => booking_path(@booking), :html => { :method => :put } do |form|
  %ul
    - @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %li= msg

      = label :booking, :status
      = form.text_field :status

      - form.fields_for :user do |user_form| 

      = user_form.label :user, :fullname
      = user_form.text_field :fullname

      = form.submit "Update this booking"
```

Thanks for you answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haml is all about indentation.  The actual usage of rails helpers etc doesn't change at all.  When you indent a line by 2 spaces, it is understood that your indented section is contained *within* the previous line that was non-indented.  Thus this:

```
%ul#hello
  %li My List Item
```

Becomes this:

```
<ul id='hello'>
  <li>My List Item</li>
</ul>
```

This applies to `do` blocks also.  If you have a rails helper you need to indent the block of the helper just as you would the rest of the markup.  Haml will automatically add the `end` when the indentation ends.  You should change your markup to look like this, I've added some comments for clarity:

```
= form_for :booking, :url => booking_path(@booking), :html => { :method => :put } do |form|
  %ul
    - @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      -# This is looking good so far... correct indent inside this `do` block
      %li= msg

      -# I don't feel like we are in the error messages block anymore, but you were still indented here.  I've removed the indentation to indicate that we are no longer in that block.

    -# This will work fine, but is there a reason you didn't use `form.label :status` here?
    = label :booking, :status
    = form.text_field :status

    -# I've changed this to use `= form.` because I believe the other version (-) is deprecated
    = form.fields_for :user do |user_form|
      -# You didn't have this indented correctly.  To be part of the do block you need to indent it appropriately.  Fixed.
      = user_form.label :fullname
      = user_form.text_field :fullname

    -# This is no longer part of the `fields_for` call, so I have removed the indentation again to indicate that this is part of the outer section.
    = form.submit "Update this booking"
```

Hopefully this was helpful :)  Haml might feel a little awkward at first but I have found that it greatly assists development speeds and to me is MUCH easier to read and write.  Took me about a week but it grew on me and now I'll never look back :p

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working through a similar issue,

Here's the parent class...

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
end
```

And the child class...

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

What I've found is that the form for creating a new Meeting requires both the @project and @meeting (the new meeting object) to be present...

```
= form_for [@project,@meeting] do |f|
  ...
```

Whereas the form for editing an existing Meeting only needs the @meeting object...

```
= form_for @meeting do |f|
  ...
```

You could take the form out of a partial (assuming you're using the Rails convention of using _form.html.haml for your form) and just have edit.html.haml and new.html.haml, but I suspect this is a comme